# state and capitals quiz questions how can I map the answers with options

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have quiz question like 
what is the capital of india

```
a,delhi 
b,bombay 
c,chennai 
d,bengaluru
```

answer in a different column as A 
I what to put a column which will check the answer a and get the option in the
 result field 
[image]

[image: Image of the error I was getting]

If I use this function `=INDEX(B2:E2,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$E$1,0))`  the first and second line is getting answer not sure why the lines like the third are showing NA in result :( @basic
Hey @basic This is the formula 
[formula I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz6Ax.png)

Comment: Your question shows no effort for solving this on your own. What have you tried? Before you post anything else here, please learn [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(B2:E2,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Add an example with data where the formula does not work.

Comment: Hey Buddy can you please check the Question Again I have edited. I am really not able to get this done

Comment: @ITO Show me formula in that cell where you get #N/A. And row numbers and col letters also.

Comment: @basuc I have put in the screenshot as formula I have used

Comment: Formula and ranges in it are correct. It must return result. Check that cells `E1` or `F3` does not contain a space(s) after `D`

Comment: yeah thats the culprit :)  Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you like to use HLOOKUP for this.

`=HLOOKUP(F2, B1:E2, 2, FALSE)`

The function looks for a match in the first row of the range specified - here B1:E2 - and returns the value in the 2nd row, as specified by the number 2 in the formula.

This formula will throw an error if no match is found, perhaps because the user entered "Y". You can use this for your purposes by embedding the formula in an IFERROR function as is demonstrated below.

`=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(F2, B1:E2, 2, FALSE),"Select a valid choice")`